# Regex. How can I tell processor to start match from the first symbol only ?

Tags: regex

It's a simple question I guess :)

"bcd" regular expression pattern matches strings like "abcd" and "bcde"
how shall I modify this pattern to make it match only "bcde" pattern (not "abcd", "1bcd", "@3bcd") ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `^` anchor to instruct the regex to start matching from the beginning of the string, so `^bcd` will match `bcd`, `bcde`, `bcdef`, etc but will not match `abcd`, `bc`, etc.

EDIT: I am not sure if you are after this, but, if you want the regex to match exclusively `bcde`, you will have to use another anchor, this being the `$` in conjunction with the `^` anchor, so your regex will now become `^bcde$`. This will instruct the regular expression engine to start matching from the first character of the string and stop matching at the end of the string, so the regex `^bcde$` will match just the string `bcde`, not `abcde`, `bcdeg`, `abcdef`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`^` matches the start of the string that the regular expression is applied to.  So try `^bcd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
bcde
```

as the regex which matches the string `bcde` and nothing else.

Note that depending on the language you are using you might have to add appropriate anchors like:

```
^bcde$
```